# Multiplexer is not simulating changes

Tags: embedded, vhdl, fpga, xilinx, vivado

I am pretty new in FPGAs and I am trying to implement a MUX at the moment.

Currently my Code looks like this

```
entity mux4x1 is
    Port ( S : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
           E : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
           Y : out std_logic);
end mux4x1;

architecture Behavioral of mux4x1 is
signal outputBuff: std_logic;
begin
        Y <= outputBuff; 
        with S select
        outputBuff <=   E(0) when "00",
                        E(1) when "01",
                        E(2) when "10",
                        E(3) when "11",
                        '0' when others;
                              
end Behavioral;
```

Unfortunately everytime I try to simulate the code and change the values of input "S" the values of E are not changing!

When I try to create a Bitstream it shows following Error Report:

```
Vivado Commands
General Messages
[USF-XSim-62] 'elaborate' step failed with error(s). Please check the Tcl console output or 'C:/Users/John Bryan Valle/Documents/Vivado/Programme/Artix-7/MUX4X1/MUX4X1.sim/sim_1/behav/xsim/elaborate.log' file for more information.

[Vivado 12-4473] Detected error while running simulation. Please correct the issue and retry this operation.

Synthesis
[Designutils 20-970] Unrecognized or unsupported command 'set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {E[2]}}]' found in constraint file. ["C:/Users/John Bryan Valle/Documents/Vivado/Programme/Artix-7/Lab-1/Lab 1 Full Adder/BASYS 3/Full_Adder_2.xdc":55]

Implementation
Design Initialization
[Designutils 20-970] Unrecognized or unsupported command 'set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {E[2]}}]' found in constraint file. ["C:/Users/John Bryan Valle/Documents/Vivado/Programme/Artix-7/Lab-1/Lab 1 Full Adder/BASYS 3/Full_Adder_2.xdc":55]

Place Design
DRC
Pin Planning
IO Standard
[DRC BIVC-1] Bank IO standard Vcc: Conflicting Vcc voltages in bank 14. For example, the following two ports in this bank have conflicting VCCOs:  
E[2] (LVCMOS18, requiring VCCO=1.800) and E[0] (LVCMOS33, requiring VCCO=3.300)

[Vivado_Tcl 4-23] Error(s) found during DRC. Placer not run.
```

Thank you in Advance! :)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjDPL.png)

Comment: Note the error message says: "'elaborate' step failed with error(s). Please check the Tcl console output or 'C:.../sim_1/behav/xsim/elaborate.log' file for more information." So elaboration (roughly, the linker stage of compilation) failed. Check the aforementioned file for more information : and if necessary, add that info to the question.

Comment: Choosing the error message that matches the title ("[USF-XSim-62] 'elaborate' step failed with error(s).") what error and warning messages were found in the elaborate.log? With the inclusion of a context clause (`library ieee; use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;`) prior to the entity declaration your code is capable of analyzing (compiling), elaborating (linking) and running (loading and execution) in other simulators. The remaining errors relate to an XDC file that doesn't match the target device. 'Run Simulation' at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your data type is not the `bit` type, you should use its library. You have used `std_logic_vector` data type. So you need to call the implementing library of it. The library is called `std_logic_1164`.
Also, there is no need to define an intermediate buffer, but its presence is not a problem

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all

entity mux4x1 is
  Port ( S : in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
         E : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         Y : out std_logic);
end mux4x1;

architecture Behavioral of mux4x1 is
begin
    with S select
    Y <=   E(0) when "00",
           E(1) when "01",
           E(2) when "10",
           E(3) when "11",
           '0'  when others;
                              
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Thx for your reply my program works sucessfully now!

Answer (score 1):

E is an input, so you wouldn't expect it to change of its own accord in simulation - rather, changes in E and S will affect Y.